# How is an icon theme supposed to be organised?

Tags: icons, standard

While trying to find out the icon used for a mimetype, I noticed that `gnome` and `oxygen` icon themes on my Arch Linux and Ubuntu 14.04 had the following folder structures:

```
gnome/48x48:
apps  mimetypes

gnome/32x32:
apps  mimetypes
...
oxygen/128x128:
actions  apps  categories  devices  emblems  emotes  mimetypes  places  status

oxygen/16x16:
actions  animations  apps  categories  devices  emblems  emotes  mimetypes  places  special  status
...
```

Sizes first, then types in them.

In Xubuntu's default themes (`elementary-xfce*`), the ordering was reversed:

```
elementary-xfce/actions/:
128  16  22  24  32  48  64  96  symbolic

elementary-xfce/animations/:
128  16  22  24  32  48  64

elementary-xfce/apps/:
128  16  22  24  32  48  64  96  symbolic

elementary-xfce/categories/:
128  16  22  24  32  48  64  96  symbolic

elementary-xfce-darker/actions/:
128  16  22  24  32  48  64  symbolic

elementary-xfce-darkest/actions/:
128  16  22  24  32  48  64  symbolic
```

Presumably both work. Are there two standard ways to organise icon themes? If not, which is the standard way?

The [specification on freedesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) only says:

> In the theme directory are also a set of subdirectories containing
>   image files. Each directory contains icons designed for a certain
>   nominal icon size, as described by the index.theme file. The
>   subdirectories are allowed to be several levels deep, e.g. the
>   subdirectory "48x48/apps" in the theme "hicolor" would end up at
>   $basedir/hicolor/48x48/apps.

The pseudocode given doesn't seem to make a distinction, unless I missed something. However, the part about applications adding their own icons favours one way:

> So, you're an application author, and want to install application
>   icons so that they work in the KDE and Gnome menus. Minimally you
>   should install a 48x48 icon in the hicolor theme. This means
>   installing a PNG file in `$prefix/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps`.
>   Optionally you can install icons in different sizes. For example,
>   installing a svg icon in `$prefix/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps`
>   means most desktops will have one icon that works for all sizes. You
>   might even want to install icons with a look that matches other well
>   known themes so your application will fit in with some specific
>   desktop environment.

Is it anything goes? Or are the Xubuntu icon themes buggy?

Comment: They both work as the standard only requires the presence of _index.theme_ (this is where you actually specify how your directories are organised). So basically, anything goes as long as you specify which is what in your _index.theme_. I would say that the gnome/oxygen way is the proper way though (that's how most icon sets are organised anyway).

Comment: So an end-user or third party attempting to find a suitable location must parse `index.theme`? I guess that answers this question, then.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Also (just in case you are dealing with several `index.theme` that are placed in different location but define the same theme) note that, per the spec, the first `index.theme` that is found [will be used](http://xdg.freedesktop.narkive.com/uKOQlXxY/icon-theme-spec-and-multiple-index-theme).

Comment: @don_crissti I wasn't.. I was trying to answer http://askubuntu.com/a/712230/158442, and was going to suggest looking in `<theme>/*x*/mimetypes`, when I noticed that Xubuntu's themes have `mimes` instead of `mimetypes` and the order reversed.